# how to compare two arrays and get the lowest one and add zeros

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am new to java I created two arraylists then ask the user for a number in a while loop once I got the desired amount of numbers from the user from point 1 and point 2. I converted the arraylists to arrays. I need to compare the two point arrays and then set the missing numbers of the lowest one to zero.
for example

- point1=(12,123,123,435,6756,667)//6 numbers
- point2=(23,13,35)//3 numbers
- point3=(23,13,35,0,0,0)//new array to replace point2 and add zeros
  -

I dont know how to compare this two arrays and add zeros to the lowest array. Any help would be appreciated.

---

my 3 objects on main

```
Point2 point1 = new Point2();
Point2 point2 = new Point2(); 
Point2 point3 = new Point2();
```

---

the way I converted the arraylist to arrays

```
Double dimPt1[] = new Double[ dimList1.size() ];
dimList1.toArray(dimPt1);
point1 = new Point2(dimPt1);
```

---

main

```
if (point1.length > point2.length)
      {

      }
      else if (point2.length > point1.lenght)
      {

      }
      else
      {
      System.out.print("Point 1 : ");
      point1.printPoints();
      System.out.print("Point 2 : ");
      point2.printPoints();
      }
```

Comment: what is lowest? amount of values?

Comment: Find the shortest list. Find the size of the largest list. Add 0 to the shortest list until its size is equal to the size of the largest list. And only then, if you really needs arrays, transform both lists to arrays. But why would you need arrays, when you already have ArrayLists?

Comment: The question is not clear to me, or it is just to me! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you can't manipulate the size of an array. Therefore, you should change the `ArrayList`s before converting to arrays:

```
int size1 = dimList1.size();
int size2 = dimList2.size();
int maxSize = Math.max(size1, size2);
if (size1 < maxSize) {
    fillZeros(dimList1, maxSize);
} else {
    fillZeros(dimList2, maxSize);
}


private void fillZeros(ArrayList<Double> list, int maxSize) {
    for(int i = list.size(); i < maxSize; i++) {
        list.add(0.0D);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's more efficient dealing with [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of dealing with regular array.

see this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    if(list1.size() < list2.size()) {
        fillZeros(list1, list2.size());
    } else {
        fillZeros(list2, list1.size());
    }
}

private static void fillZeros(ArrayList list, int size) {
    int zerosToAdd = size - list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < zerosToAdd; i++) {
        list.add(0);
    }
}
```

then convert the result Arraylist if you want

Comment: So I have to deal with the uneven arraylists first and the convert them to an array. So I dont have to create another object.

Comment: Yea, and for more details take a loot at Java Collections.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Comment: I am trying to run your code and see if it works but I keep getting an error (3 errors found:
File: G:\NewCode\Testor2.java  [line: 97]
Error: Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
File: G:\NewCode\Testor2.java  [line: 97]
Error: Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
File: G:\NewCode\Testor2.java  [line: 97]
Error: Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

Comment: the error is on the private void fillZeros(ArrayList list,int size)

Comment: Could you please put what you have tried (your code), so i can figure out the root cause of this error.

Comment: I got it working I was placing the fillZeros contructor on the main.

Comment: cong, so please don't forget to make mark it as answer, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I don't really understand your meaning.what's the relationship between ponit1 and point2 and point3?

Comment: If you don't understand something you should really ask for it in a comment not as an answer.

Comment: I am new here.So sorry.

Comment: It's OK it's just a little tip so you won't get downvoted as often.